# Deploy to azure error

Tags: virtocommerce

I've tried to deploy virtocommerce to azure following the steps available at http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1devguide/Source+Code+Azure+Deployment , but I'm getting some errors during the build...

```
MSBUILD 4.0 Path = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
03/03/2015 17:21:12 - Solution Build: In progress
Version: 1.0.62.1721
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.33440
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34014]
```

Build started 03/03/2015 17:21:12.

```
 1>Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\VirtoCommerce.sln" on node 1 (clean target(s)).

 1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:

     Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".

   ValidateProjects:

     The project "Performance.FunctionalTests" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".

   The target "MSDeployPublish" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.2\tools\webjobs.wap.targets (89,11)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.

   The target "MSDeployPublish" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.2\tools\webjobs.wap.targets (156,11)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.

 1>Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\VirtoCommerce.sln" (1) is building "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WorkerRoles\Scheduler\AzureScheduler\AzureScheduler.ccproj" (61) on node 7 (Clean target(s)).
```

C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WorkerRoles\Scheduler\AzureScheduler\AzureScheduler.ccproj(68,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.4\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

```
61>Done Building Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WorkerRoles\Scheduler\AzureScheduler\AzureScheduler.ccproj" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.

 1>Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\VirtoCommerce.sln" (1) is building "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WebRoles\Frontend\CommerceSite\CommerceSite.ccproj" (62) on node 2 (Clean target(s)).

62>C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WebRoles\Frontend\CommerceSite\CommerceSite.ccproj(71,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.4\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets**" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

62>Done Building Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WebRoles\Frontend\CommerceSite\CommerceSite.ccproj" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.

 1>Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\VirtoCommerce.sln" (1) is building "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WorkerRoles\Search\ElasticSearch\ElasticSearch.ccproj" (66) on node 6 (Clean target(s)).
66>C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WorkerRoles\Search\ElasticSearch\ElasticSearch.ccproj(70,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.4\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets**" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
66>Done Building Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WorkerRoles\Search\ElasticSearch\ElasticSearch.ccproj" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.

 1>Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\VirtoCommerce.sln" (1) is building "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Extensions\Jobs\SchedulerConsole\SchedulerConsole.csproj" (69) on node 1 (Clean target(s)).

69>C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.2\tools\webjobs.console.targets(25,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Extensions\Jobs\SchedulerConsole\SchedulerConsole.csproj]
69>Done Building Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Extensions\Jobs\SchedulerConsole\SchedulerConsole.csproj" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.
 1>Done Building Project "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\VirtoCommerce.sln" (clean target(s)) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.




   "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\VirtoCommerce.sln" (clean target) (1) ->

   "C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WorkerRoles\Scheduler\AzureScheduler\AzureScheduler.ccproj" (Clean target) (61) ->

     C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\Azure\WorkerRoles\Scheduler\AzureScheduler\AzureScheduler.ccproj(68,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.4\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

...
Build Failed

```
At C:\code\github\VirtoCommerceCommunity\vc-community-master\src\extensions\Setup\VirtoCommerce.PowerShell\azure-deploy.ps1:445 char:11

+           throw "Build Failed"
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Build Failed:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Build Failed
```

I've tried from different machines (Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012), both with Visual Studio 2013, and found the same error...
Interesting that on both machines the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools does not exists...
The Azure Tools only exists at the \VisualStuion\v12.0 directory...

How could we solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related how msbuild is packaged with VS.NET 2013 (http://blog.maskalik.com/msbuild/2014/03/04/changes-in-msbuild-with-visual-studio-2013/). In order for powershell deploy to work out of the box, VS.NET 2012 needs to be installed. The workaround is to modify azure-deploy.ps1 to point to the MSBuild from VS.NET 2013 instead of .NET SDK.

So change line 426 from

```
$global:buildexe_path = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0" -Name MSBuildToolsPath).MSBuildToolsPath
```

to (simply changed 4.0 to 12.0)

```
$global:buildexe_path = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0" -Name MSBuildToolsPath).MSBuildToolsPath
```

It will be included in the next patch once it passes our CI.